# Zip 4 observables in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, readability

I have to make 4 api calls and wait until all of them are finished. I want to handle every data separately with their names, but can't figure it out how to do it in kotlin.

```
    val observables = mutableListOf<Single<ApiResponse>>()

    observables.add(repository.getFirstApiData())
    observables.add(repository.getSecondApiData())
    observables.add(repository.getThirdApiData())
    observables.add(repository.getFourthApiData())

    Single.zip(observables) { array ->

    }
            .subscribe()
```

This is working fine, but i dont want to iterate by array but I want to map it somehow into 4 variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this

```
    Single.zip(
        repository.getFirstApiData(),
        repository.getSecondApiData(),
        repository.getThirdApiData(),
        repository.getFourthApiData(),
        Function4<ApiResponse, ApiResponse, ApiResponse, ApiResponse, Unit> { t1, t2, t3, t4 ->
            println("$t1 $t2 $t3 $t4")
        }
    ).subscribe()
```

Comment: I try that way and i got an error: "Type inference failed. Not enough information to infer parameter R in ...